# How to correctly format hydrates with chemformula?

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

`Chemformula` has a quite convenient `.` command to put in adduct. However, if I were to put in something like `\ch{UO2(NO3).6H2O}` I get the 6 as a subscript. If I put in 2 spaces (`\ch{UO2(NO3). 6 H2O}`) I get a full height number, but there are spaces that should not be present. Is there a way to get a proper adduct (hydrate, "ate complex")?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{formula=chemformula, %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
    } 

\begin{document}

\ch{UO2(NO3).6H2O}

\ch{UO2(NO3). 6 H2O}

\end{document}
```